# BeautifulSoup - How do I extract a substring of a string between tags?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I would like to search the HTML for "Website:" and then return "http://www.aa.com"

```
<br>Website:  <a href="http://www.aa.com">http://www.aa.com</a><br>
```

I'm not sure what to do here since there is a clause in between the two strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search for the text; the result in a `NavigableString` object, which retains information about where in the tree it lives, which means you can ask it for the next sibling from that element:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import re
>>> sample = '''\
... <br>Website:  <a href="http://www.aa.com">http://www.aa.com</a><br>
... '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(sample)
>>> soup.find(text=re.compile('Website:'))
u'Website:  '
>>> soup.find(text=re.compile('Website:')).next_sibling
<a href="http://www.aa.com">http://www.aa.com</a>
```

Once you have the `<a>` element getting either the `href` attribute or the contained text is trivial:

```
>>> soup.find(text=re.compile('Website:')).next_sibling['href']
'http://www.aa.com'
>>> soup.find(text=re.compile('Website:')).next_sibling.string
u'http://www.aa.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of your content as a tree rather than a string.
Beautifulsoup gives you access to the parse tree, issue a `findall('a')`, then navigate the parsetree whith [`parent()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-up) and [`contents()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-down), You can navigate to [siblings](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-sideways) too.